# Can't assign a command for FN key

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, brightness

I've an ASUS F555L whith Ubuntu-GNOME 16.10 and I've a problem with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.

I'm trying to set the brightness UP/DOWN with the key *<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>* and *<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>*.
I solved the brightness issue setting the command with the Key Shotcuts in *Setting> Keyboard > Custum Shortcuts* in this way:

```
name: Brightness Up 
command: xdotool key --clearmodifiers XF86MonBrightnessUp
```

and

```
name: Brightness Down 
command: xdotool key --clearmodifiers XF86MonBrightnessDown
```

When I tried to set these Shortcuts with the key <kbd>Fn</kbd> nothing happened, like the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key doesn't exist or work.

I tried to see with `acpi_listen` if the keys work but with *<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>* or *<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>* there isn't an output.

But it doesn't make sense because with *<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>* the output is

```
button/mute MUTE 00000080 00000000 K
```

How can i make work *<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>/<kbd>F6</kbd>* ? Is there a command on the terminal to enable the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key?

Comment: `<Fn><F5>` is a key in its own right. The `<Fn>` key [works at the hardware/firmware level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495426/is-fn-key-not-defined-in-x-window-in-x11-keysymdef-h).

Comment: Use `xev` from terminal, and check your keypresses for their labels/ID.

Comment: When I use `xev` whith only  <Fn> or with <Fn>+<F5>/<F6> nothing happened.

Comment: Related possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/866437/function-keys-do-not-work-brightness-sound-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to try to define Custom Key Shortcuts. You can do it directly on follow way on Ubuntu, Linux Mint and Debian.

```
xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessUp

xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessDown
```